# Dynamic cast in Haxe

Tags: haxe, dynamic-cast

**Is it possible to cast a variable to another type based on information available at runtime?**

If I have:

```
interface Foo
{
}

class Bar implements Foo
{
    public function new()
    {
    }
}
```

I want to do something like this (method is simplified for clarity):

```
public static function dynamicCast<T : Foo>(target : Foo, cls : Class<T>) : T
{
    var ret : T = cast(pTarget, cls);
    return ret;
}
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Unexpected )
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer in the [official haxe documentation](http://haxe.org/ref/dynamic#unsafe-cast). Here it is:

```
public static function dynamicCast<T : Foo>(target : Foo, cls : Class<T>) : T
{
    if(Std.is(target, cls))
    {
        var ret : T = cast target;
        return ret;
    }
    return null;
}
```